# How can I get the amounts of various characters from strings in C++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to use a C++ program to get a string from the user, and calculate and output how many spaces the user used, how many letters, and how many digits from 1-9. This is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        char instr[255];
        printf("Input characters, up to 255,  and Number of various 
        characters \nwill be calculated and output.\nPress any key to 
        continue.\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c%c", &instr);
        getch();
        system("CLS");
        printf("String Value: %s\n", instr);
        getch();
        return 0;
   }
```

The result: I can successfully input and output a string, however I am unaware of any ways of finding the character values.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking forward something like this

```
 string a;
    getline(cin,a);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    int space=0,line=0,digit=0,letter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==' ')
            space++;
        else if(a[i]>='A' && a[i]<='z')
            letter++;
        else if(a[i]>='0' && a[i]<='9') digit++;
        else;

    }
    cout<<space<<"  "<<letter<<"  "<<digit<<endl;
```